# How does the sympy library work for factorising inputs?

Tags: python, sympy

Hi I am new to programming and I am trying to factorise the inputs of a polynomial, however whenever I do it the programme just returns the same input and I was just wondering why?

Any help would be much appreciated thank you.

```py
import sympy 
from sympy import symbols 
from sympy import factor

x = symbols('x') 

equ = input('Enter equation:')

factorised = factor(equ)

print("factorised form: ", factorised)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you are trying, and the output you would expect?

Comment: It is impossible to answer without knowing what you types as input but it is possible that you are passing in an expression that does not factorise. It is possible that you are hoping for SymPy to compute the roots of the polynomial but that is not what the `factor` function is for.

Comment: So in the sympy documentation: factor(x**3 - x**2 + x - 1) returns the answer = (x-1) * (x^2+1).

I was just wondering why when I ask for a input and use the function it doesn't give out the same output it just outputs whatever equation the user has inputed

Answer (score 0):

- `input()` function in Python treats the user's input as a `string`. Therefore, when you pass the equation to the `factor()` function, it treats it as a `string` and not as a `mathematical expression`.
- you can use the `sympify()` function from the `sympy` module to convert the input string into a `mathematical expression`.

```
import sympy
from sympy import symbols, factor, sympify

x = symbols('x')

equ = input('Enter equation: ')
equation = sympify(equ)

factorised = factor(equation)

print("Factorized form: ", factorised)
```

PS- Give full information like what are you trying to `input`..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works. Try to input this expression and see if you get the same result:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> factor('x**2 - 1')
(x - 1)*(x + 1)
```